# unable to connect spider closed when yielding to s3 bucket

Tags: scrapy

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy.signalmanager import SignalManager
#from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy import signals
class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'forever'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    kohlind = max_kohls = 0
    total_products = 0
    colected = 0
    items = []
    #AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'id'
    #AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'pass'
    start_urls=['https://www.example.com/']
    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI' : f's3://example-products/fulltest.csv',
    'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['ITEM_ID','URL','SELLER','PRICE','SALE_PRICE','MAIN_IMAGE','OTHER_IMAGE','SKU','PRODUCT_NAME']

    }
    def __init__(self):
        SignalManager(dispatcher.Any).connect(receiver=self._close, signal=signals.spider_closed)
#spider code
    def _close(self):
        print(f"\n\nClosing Spider with {len(self.items)} New Items")
        for i in self.items:
            if "URL" in i.keys():
                yield item

        print("Done")
```

Program is not connecting to `_close` function, no error is found and the yield items in spider code are uploaded normally (except the _close nothing happens)

I tried removing the s3 in the settings, It worked fine (i.e entered the _close function)

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code below, and it should work

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'forever'

    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        print(f"\n\nClosing Spider with {len(self.items)} New Items")
```